# JAVA Snake Game Error. The snake stops after 3 steps

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, awt

This is my first query here. I am building a snake game which runs perfectly but the body moves only three steps and pauses. The following is the code for the gameplay, i have the main method, but its absolutely fine. [Image : before pressing right arrow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG12Q.png)..........
[Image : after pressing right arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2I4n.png)

Main Method :

```
public class Snake {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Gameplay gplay = new Gameplay();
    JFrame obj = new JFrame();
    obj.setTitle("Super SNake");
    obj.setBounds(10, 10, 905, 700);
    obj.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(192, 68, 66));
    obj.setResizable(false);
    obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    obj.add(gplay);
    obj.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Gameplay code :

```
public class Gameplay extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener{

private int[] snakeXlength = new int[750];
private int[] snakeYlength = new int[750];
private int lengthsnake = 3;
private int moves = 0;

private boolean left = false;
private boolean right = false;
private boolean up = false;
private boolean down = false;

private ImageIcon umouth;
private ImageIcon lmouth;
private ImageIcon rmouth;
private ImageIcon dmouth;

private ImageIcon body;
private ImageIcon imagetitle;

private Timer t;
private int delay = 100;

public Gameplay(){

    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    t = new Timer(delay,this);
    t.start();

}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    if(moves==0){

        snakeXlength[2] = 50;
        snakeXlength[1] = 75;
        snakeXlength[0] = 100;

        snakeYlength[2] = 100;
        snakeYlength[1] = 100;
        snakeYlength[0] = 100;
    }


    //title border
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(24, 10, 851, 55);
    //title
    imagetitle = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("title.jpg"));
    imagetitle.paintIcon(this, g, 25, 11);
    //play area
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(24, 74, 851, 577);
    //bg for play area
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(25, 75, 850, 575);
    rmouth = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("rmouth.png") );
    //rmouth = new ImageIcon("game/rmouth.png");
    rmouth.paintIcon(this, g, snakeXlength[0], snakeYlength[0]);

    for(int a=0; a<lengthsnake; a++){
        if(a==0 && right){
        rmouth = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("rmouth.png") );
        //rmouth = new ImageIcon("rmouth.png");
        rmouth.paintIcon(this, g, snakeXlength[a], snakeYlength[a]);
        }
        if(a==0 && left){
        lmouth = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("lmouth.png") );
        //lmouth = new ImageIcon("lmouth.png");
        lmouth.paintIcon(this, g, snakeXlength[a], snakeYlength[a]);
        }
        if(a==0 && up){
        umouth = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("umouth.png") );
        //umouth = new ImageIcon("umouth.png");
        umouth.paintIcon(this, g, snakeXlength[a], snakeYlength[a]);
        }
        if(a==0 && down){
        dmouth = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("dmouth.png") );
        //dmouth = new ImageIcon("dmouth.png");
        dmouth.paintIcon(this, g, snakeXlength[a], snakeYlength[a]);
        }
        if(a!=0){
        body = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("body.png") );
        //body = new ImageIcon("body.png");
        body.paintIcon(this, g, snakeXlength[a], snakeYlength[a]);
        }
        }
        g.dispose();
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
     if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
    moves++;
    right= true;
    if(!left){
     right=true;
    }
    else{
    right= false;
    left= true;
    }
}

if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
 moves++;
left= true;
if(!right){
left=true;
}
else{
 left= false;
 right= true;
}
up=false;
down=false;
}
if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_UP){
moves++;
up= true;
if(!down){
up=true;
}
else{
up= false;
down= true;
}

left=false;
right=false;
}

if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
moves++;
down= true;
if(!up){
down=true;
}
else{
down= false;
up= true;
}

left=false;
right=false;
}

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    t.start();

if(right){

for(int r= lengthsnake-1; r>=0; r--){
snakeYlength[r+1]= snakeYlength[r];
}
for(int r=lengthsnake; r>0; r--){
if(r==0){
 snakeXlength[r]= snakeXlength[r]+25;
}
else{
 snakeXlength[r]= snakeXlength[r-1];
}

if(snakeXlength[r]> 850){
 snakeXlength[r]= 25;
}
}

repaint();
}

    if(left){

    for(int r= lengthsnake-1; r>=0; r--){
snakeYlength[r+1]= snakeYlength[r];
}
for(int r=lengthsnake; r>0; r--){
if(r==0){
 snakeXlength[r]= snakeXlength[r] -25;
}
else{
 snakeXlength[r]= snakeXlength[r-1];
}

if(snakeXlength[r]< 25){
 snakeXlength[r]= 850;
}
}

repaint();
    }
    if(up){

    for(int r= lengthsnake-1; r>=0; r--){
snakeXlength[r+1]= snakeXlength[r];
}
for(int r=lengthsnake; r>0; r--){
if(r==0){
 snakeYlength[r]= snakeYlength[r]+25;
}
else{
 snakeYlength[r]= snakeYlength[r-1];
}

if(snakeYlength[r]< 625){
 snakeYlength[r]= 75;
}
}

repaint();
}
    if(down){

    for(int r= lengthsnake-1; r>=0; r--){
snakeXlength[r+1]= snakeXlength[r];
}
for(int r=lengthsnake; r>0; r--){
if(r==0){
 snakeYlength[r]= snakeYlength[r] +25;
}
else{
 snakeYlength[r]= snakeYlength[r-1];
}

if(snakeYlength[r] > 625){
 snakeYlength[r]= 75;
}
}

repaint();
    }

    }

}
```

I hope you will be able to help me with my problem.
I don't know where i am wrong. The snake moves but stops after 3 steps, its still changing direction of head but in that position only. This is my first query here in stack overflow. I hope the above data helps to understand the problem. Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: The first 'non generic' tips I'd offer are: 1) Don't forget to ask a question. 2)  Images should be loaded once & stored as class attributes. 3) For the MCVE / SSCCE, one way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). 4) `public void paint(Graphics g){` For any `JComponent`, the correct method is `paintComponent(Graphics)` - always call the super method first, either way. 5) Use `@Override` notation whenever changing method functionality. It is a compilation sanity check for correct method spelling & signature.

Comment: Your mashing logic in both the `paint` and `ActionListener`, this is bad idea, ALL your logic should exist in the `ActionListener` and the `paint` method should paint the current state

Comment: You also never "release" any key state, so it's repeatedly going around through the key state processing endlessly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are a number of things "wrong", but I'll start with the most obvious issue.

Look only at the `right` direction handler...

```
for (int r = lengthsnake; r > 0; r--) {
    if (r == 0) {
        snakeXlength[r] = snakeXlength[r] + 25;
    } else {
        snakeXlength[r] = snakeXlength[r - 1];
    }

    if (snakeXlength[r] > 850) {
        snakeXlength[r] = 25;
    }
}
```

There is no way that `r` can be equal to `0` in this loop, which means, the `0` element never changes.

It should be more like...

```
for (int r = lengthsnake; r > 0; r--) {
    snakeXlength[r] = snakeXlength[r - 1];

    if (snakeXlength[r] > 850) {
        snakeXlength[r] = 25;
    }
}
snakeXlength[0] = snakeXlength[0] + 25;
if (snakeXlength[0] > 850) {
    snakeXlength[0] = 25;
}
```

I suspect all the other "direction" handlers have the same issue.

Next...

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    t.start();
    //...
```

Starting the timer in it's own `ActionListener` probably isn't the best idea.  A Swing `Timer` will repeat by itself automatically.

Next...

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (moves == 0) {
    //...
    g.dispose();
}
```

is a bag of bad ideas.

First, as general recommendation, you should avoid overriding `paint`.  Instead, you should focus on overriding `paintComponent`.

You should also call the `paint` method's `super`, to maintain the paint chain.

You should never dispose of a `Graphics` context you didn't create yourself, it can have adverse effects on other things which need to be painted after your component.

Instead, something more like...

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (moves == 0) {
    //...
}
```

Next...

I've given up even discussing `KeyListener` - instead, you should be using [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Next...

You never release any of the key states, this is going to be very problematic and the direction of the head should actually be managed separately from the key state and the paint process

## Suggestions...

Use a different data structure to manage your snake.  Something like a `LinkedList` would be find if you only need linear access (or `ArrayList` if you need random access).  The point is, you can easily insert a new element at the "head" of the `List` with having to "copy" all the old elements over one place.

I would create two more elements.  One to manage the "type" of element and one to manage the location of the element.

```
public enum SnakePartType {
    LEFT_HEAD, RIGHT_HEAD, DOWN_HEAD, UP_HEAD, BODY
}

public class SnakePart {
    private SnakePartType type;
    private Point location; // You could use separate x/y properties, but Point already does it

    public SnakePart(SnakePartType type, Point location) {
        this.type = type;
        this.location = location;
    }

    // Getters for type and location
}
```

This way, your `paint` process doesn't need to know about the key state, which will change between paint passes and can rely on the information in the model instead

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to figure out the changes for other direction handlers and viola! it works